# Tensoring an abelian group with a divisible abelian group

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, commutative-algebra, tensor-products, abelian-groups

$\newcommand{\Tors}{{\rm Tors}}
\newcommand{\tf}{{\rm t.f.}}$
Let $A$ be an abelian group. We denote by $A_\Tors$ the torsion subgroup of $A$.
We set $A_\tf=A/A_\Tors$,, which is a torsion free abelian group.

We say that an abelian group $B$ is *divisible*, if for any element $b\in B$ and any natural $n\in{\Bbb Z}_{>0}$
there exists an element $b'\in B$ (maybe non-unique) such that $n b'=b$.

I am looking for a reference for the following well-known lemma:

> **Lemma.** Let $A$ be an abelian group and $B$ be a divisible abelian group.
> Consider the canonical homomorphism
> $$\tf\colon A\to A_\tf:= A/A_\Tors\,.$$
> Then the induced homomorphism
> $$(\tf)_*\colon A\otimes B\to A_\tf\otimes B$$
> is an isomorphism.

I know a proof of this lemma; I am looking for a reference.

Comment: (I am putting this as a comment instead of an answer since you asked for a reference and not an answer.) This map has no cokernel and its kernel is $A_\text{Tors}$, so the result follows immediately from "torsion tensor divisible equals zero" and the right-exactness of the tensor product, both of which I think are sufficiently well-known that you should be able to get away with putting this in a paper without a citation.

Comment: For what its worth, Fuchs mentions this fact in Section 59, item D, in *Infinite Abelian Groups, Vol. I* (Academic Press, 1970).

Comment: @hunter: I had basically the same proof, but your version is concise. I have put it into my paper. Many thanks!

Comment: @hunter: If you put your comment as an answer, I will be happy to accept it.